# Adding a decimal number to a series of zeroes

Tags: php

I am trying to add a number to a series of zeroes. For example:

- Increment 1 on '0000' to get 0001
- Increment 86 on '000000' to get 000086

How would I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

```
str_pad($input, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
    str_pad($value, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    $num_padded = sprintf("%04s", $i);
    echo "$num_padded"."<br>";
}
```

**`OUTPUT`**

```
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007.... goes on
```